# How to add to a dictionary when there may be duplicate keys?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

A bunch of key/value pairs, from an object that may have duplicate keys, need to be added to a dictionary. Only the first distinct instance of a key (and the instance's value) should be added to the dictionary.

Below is an example implementation that appears, at first, to work fine.

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<long, DateTime> items = new Dictionary<long, DateTime>();
    items = AllItems.Select(item =>
                    {
                        long value;
                        bool parseSuccess = long.TryParse(item.Key, out value);
                        return new { value = value, parseSuccess, item.Value };
                    })
                    .Where(parsed => parsed.parseSuccess && !items.ContainsKey(parsed.value))
                    .Select(parsed => new { parsed.value, parsed.Value })
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToDictionary(e => e.value, e => e.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Distinct: {0}{1}Non-distinct: {2}",items.Count, Environment.NewLine, AllItems.Count));

}

public List<KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>> AllItems
{
    get
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>> toReturn = new List<KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>>();
        for (int i = 1000; i < 1100; i++)
        {
            toReturn.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>(i.ToString(), DateTime.Now));
            toReturn.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>(i.ToString(), DateTime.Now));
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

If AllItems is modified to return many more pairs, however, then an ArgumentException occurs: "An item with the same key has already been added."

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<long, DateTime> items = new Dictionary<long, DateTime>();
    var AllItems = PartOne.Union(PartTwo);
    Console.WriteLine("Total items: " + AllItems.Count());
    items = AllItems.Select(item =>
                    {
                        long value;
                        bool parseSuccess = long.TryParse(item.Key, out value);
                        return new { value = value, parseSuccess, item.Value };
                    })
                    .Where(parsed => parsed.parseSuccess && !items.ContainsKey(parsed.value))
                    .Select(parsed => new { parsed.value, parsed.Value })
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToDictionary(e => e.value, e => e.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Distinct: {0}{1}Non-distinct: {2}",items.Count, Environment.NewLine, AllItems.Count());

}

public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>> PartOne
{
    get
    {
        for (int i = 10000000; i < 11000000; i++)
        {
            yield return (new KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>(i.ToString(), DateTime.Now));
        }
    }
}
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>> PartTwo
{
    get
    {
        for (int i = 10000000; i < 11000000; i++)
        {
            yield return (new KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>(i.ToString(), DateTime.Now));
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to accomplish this? Note that the use of `long.TryParse` needs to be present in the solution, as the real input may not include valid Int64's.

Comment: Take a look at the LINQ ToLookup() method

Comment: dictionary has ContainsKey function .  maybe you can modify your allItems and call ContainsKey before you add the keyvaluepair

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Only the first distinct instance of a key (and the instance's value)
>   should be added to the dictionary.

You can achieve this by using the [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) method and taking the first value in the group:

```
items = AllItems.Select(item =>
                {
                    long value;
                    bool parseSuccess = long.TryParse(item.Key, out value);
                    return new { Key = value, parseSuccess, item.Value };
                })
                .Where(parsed => parsed.parseSuccess)
                .GroupBy(o => o.Key)
                .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.First().Value)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would look cleaning a few things up.

Using a `Func<string, long?>` is better in a LINQ query.

```
Func<string, long?> tryParse = t =>
{
    long v;
    if (!long.TryParse(t, out v))
    {
        return null;
    }
    return v;
};
```

Then the query looks like this:

```
var query =
    from item in AllItems
    let keyValue = tryParse(item.Key)
    where keyValue.HasValue
    group item.Value by keyValue.Value into g
    select new
    {
        key = g.Key,
        value = g.First(),
    };
```

And finally create the dictionary:

```
var items = query.ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.value);
```

Fairly simple.

Thanks for providing all the code required to test the solution.

Comment: +1 for the correct "use grouping" answer. Thanks for the nice suggestion on how to clean things up. That does make the linq query look nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see - Your `Select()` is currently projecting to the anonymous type

```
new { value = value, parseSuccess, item.Value };
```

Then you filter out all items where parsing failed, so essentially you have

```
new { value = value, true, item.Value };
```

Now you use `Distinct()` on the remaining items. In this case all unique combinations of (value, Value) are considered unique. That means you can have i.e (1,2) and (1,3).

Finally you create your dictionary - but you still may have duplicate `value` keys as seen in the example above. This explains why you get this exception.

As posted already `GroupBy()` is the way to go in this case to simplify your expression.

Comment: Admittedly, the .Distinct() doesn't really do much of anything, unless there are multiple keys with the same value. However, the line `.Where(parsed => parsed.parseSuccess && !items.ContainsKey(parsed.value))` was designed to keep out the duplicates. And if you run the examples multiples times, it appears to sometimes keep out the duplicates. Or is that just a red herring?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try this yet, but something like this with a group by should work.

```
items = AllItems.Select(item =>
                {                         
                    long value;                         
                    bool parseSuccess = long.TryParse(item.Key, out value);                         
                    return new { value = value, parseSuccess, item.Value };                     
                })                     
                .Where(parsed => parsed.parseSuccess && !items.ContainsKey(parsed.value))                     
                .Select(parsed => new { parsed.value, parsed.Value })                     
                .GroupBy(x => x.value)
                .Select(x => new {value = x.Key, Value = x.Min(y => y.Value)})
                .ToDictionary(e => e.value, e => e.Value);
```